# Find a text using the Adobe Reader ActiveX control?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I'm using the Adobe Reader ActiveX control to display a PDF file in a Winforms application.

Is it possible to search for a text after the file loads and instruct the control to display that text (go to the location)?

The component supports numerous methods but strangely SearchText or FindText are not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible solution seems to be to use the WebBrowser control to load the PDF with a #search parameter following the url.  The Adobe control itself doesn't listen to that parameter.

```
  webBrowser1.Navigate("file.pdf#search=\"textTofind\"");
```

More here:
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf